# how to use Publishers.CombineLatest to get 1 publisher

Tags: swift, combine

I am trying to use 2 publishers and have them stream to 1 publisher that is mapped from both values.

My code is:

```
class ViewModel {

    let email = CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>("")

    lazy var isEmailValid = email.map { self.validateEmail(email: $0) }

    let password = CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>("")

    lazy var isPasswordCorrect = password.map {
        self.validatePassword(password: $0)
    }

    let canLogin: CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>

    private func validateEmail(email: String) -> Bool {
        return email == "1234@gmail.com"
    }

    private func validatePassword(password: String) -> Bool {
        return password == "1234"
    }


    init() {
    
        canLogin = Publishers
            .CombineLatest(isEmailValid, isPasswordCorrect)
            .map { $0 && $1 } 

    }
}
```

Then in the init I get this error:

```
    //error: Cannot assign value of type 
'Publishers.Map<Publishers.CombineLatest<Publishers.Map<CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>, 
Bool>, Publishers.Map<CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>, Bool>>, Bool>' to type 'CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>'
```

I am new to combine so I find it a little confusing.
How should I achieve, from the code above, the combination of 2 publishers isEmailValid and isPasswordCorrect, into 1 publisher that is a CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [`CurrentValueSubject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/currentvaluesubject) is:

> A subject that wraps a single value and publishes a new element whenever the value changes.

Your `canLogin` is certainly not a `CurrentValueSubject`. It is the result of combining two other publishers with the `CombineLatest` operator, and then mapping the combined publisher to yet another publisher.

In the language of the Swift type system, this kind of publisher is called:

```
Publishers.Map<Publishers.CombineLatest<Publishers.Map<CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>, Bool>, Publishers.Map<CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>, Bool>>, Bool>
```

Obviously, no one would declare a property with a type like that, so we use `eraseToAnyPublisher` to get ourselves an `AnyPublisher`, to say that we don't actually care what type of publisher it is.

```
let canLogin: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never>

...

canLogin = Publishers
        .CombineLatest(isEmailValid, isPasswordCorrect)
        .map { $0 && $1 } 
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Answer (score 2):

You've declared the type of `canLogin` completely incorrectly.

It needs to be an `AnyPublisher`, which you can get by simply calling `eraseToAnyPublisher` on the `map`.

```
lazy var canLogin: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> = isEmailValid.combineLatest(isPasswordCorrect).map { $0 && $1 }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
```