# Asynchronous iteration using Swift Combine

Tags: swift, combine

I am trying to do multiple async operations, in sequence, on an array of data. However I am having problems with the return values of `map`.

Here is the test code:

```
import Combine

func getLength(_ string: String) -> Future<Int,Error> {
    return Future<Int,Error>{ promise in
        print("Length \(string.count)")
        promise(.success(string.count))
    }
}


func isEven(_ int: Int) -> Future<Bool,Error> {
    return Future<Bool,Error>{ promise in
        print("Even \(int % 2 == 0)")
        promise(.success(int % 2 == 0))
    }
}

let stringList = ["a","bbb","c","dddd"]

func testStrings(_ strings:ArraySlice<String>) -> Future<Void,Error> {
    var remaining = strings
    
    if let first = remaining.popFirst() {
        return getLength(first).map{ length in
            return isEven(length)
        }.map{ even in
            return testStrings(remaining)
        }
    } else {
        return Future { promise in
            promise(.success(()))
        }
    }
}

var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()

testStrings(ArraySlice<String>(stringList)).sink { _ in } receiveValue: { _ in print("Done") }.store(in: &storage)
```

This generates the following error:

```
error: MyPlayground.playground:26:11: error: cannot convert return expression of type 'Publishers.Map<Future<Int, Error>, Future<Void, Error>>' to return type 'Future<Void, Error>'
        }.map{ even in
```

I thought we could use map to convert from one publisher type to the other, but it seems it's wrapped inside a `Publishers.Map`. How do I get rid of this?

Thanks!

Comment: See [this recent answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65072289/5133585). `testStrings` should not return `Future`.

Comment: What should it return then? I tried replacing it with `AnyPublisher<Void,Error>` and adding `.eraseToAnyPublisher()` but that gives me other errors

Comment: Yes that's what you should do. What other error did it give you? Please [edit] your question with what you changed, and the new error.

Comment: The issue was I needed to replace the `map` with `flatMap` (don't ask me why...)

Comment: Because you are returning another publisher inside a `map`. That's usually a good sign to use `flatMap`, to flatten the publisher of publishers :)

Comment: @JorisMans, `map` and `flatMap` are quite different. `map` emits a mapped value for each upstream value. `flatMap` maps a **publisher** for each upstream and emits all the values of that publisher.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems that this works:

```
import Combine

func getLength(_ string: String) -> Future<Int,Error> {
    return Future<Int,Error>{ promise in
        print("Length \(string.count)")
        promise(.success(string.count))
    }
}


func isEven(_ int: Int) -> Future<Bool,Error> {
    return Future<Bool,Error>{ promise in
        print("Even \(int % 2 == 0)")
        promise(.success(int % 2 == 0))
    }
}

let stringList = ["a","bbb","c","dddd"]

func testStrings(_ strings:ArraySlice<String>) -> AnyPublisher<Void,Error> {
    var remaining = strings
    
    if let first = remaining.popFirst() {
        return getLength(first).flatMap{ length in
            return isEven(length)
        }.flatMap{ even in
            return testStrings(remaining)
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    } else {
        return Future<Void,Error> { promise in
            promise(.success(()))
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()

testStrings(ArraySlice<String>(stringList)).sink { _ in } receiveValue: { _ in print("Done") }.store(in: &storage)
```